# Can anyone identify this small flash audio player?

Tags: html, flash, audio, web, identify

I see this little player every now and then, but I have no idea where it comes from or how to make one. See [here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4287) about halfway down the page for one example.

It looks like this screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I know this is not exactly a programming question, but where else should I ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the WordPress Audio Player. See http://wpaudioplayer.com/.

Comment: Wonderful :) and it appears they have a standalone version. Thanks